# PCA: How to get PC2 and PC3 scores?

Tags: pca

How I can get the score of PC2 and PC3 (Dim2 and Dim3)? I run this code which generated a graph with only PC1 and PC2 scores.

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")
mydata<- read.csv("mussels.csv", TRUE, ",")
mydata[is.na(mydata)]=0
attach(mydata)
X=cbind (As, Co, Cr, Cu, Mn, Mo, Ni, Pb, Zn)
summary(X)
cor(X)

res.pca <- princomp(X, scores=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
summary(res.pca)

fviz_pca_var(res.pca, col.var="contrib",
         gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
         repel = TRUE # Avoid text overlapping
)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Nick Cox, please kindly note, I am a fisheries biologist and we usually don't have a good command on programming. For us finding PC3 and PC4 scores without an expert helps is really impossible.

Comment: The point is simply is that this is off-topic here. For similar questions you are really are better off trying a forum that supports questions about R code. (I am not a statistician either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not have your data to work with. I'll solve your problem using `iris` dataset:

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")

res.pca <- princomp(iris[, 1:4], scores=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
summary(res.pca)

fviz_pca_var(res.pca, col.var="contrib",
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
             repel = TRUE, # Avoid text overlapping
             axes = c(2, 3) # choose PCs to plot
)
```

Notice that I just used `axes = c(2, 3)` argument inside `fviz_pca_var` function in order to plot the principal components I want.

[image]